# creating a 2d array from a funtion in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a 2d array from the onclick function, i.e every time I click it must run the function and add the arry to the existing one. i dont seem to get my head around this. i can the first array but i need the arry to acumulate into array of arrays everytime i use the onclick.

`function collectData() {

```
var star = document.querySelector('input[name=abc1]:checked').value;
var moon = document.getElementById('abc_2').value;
var sun = document.getElementById('abc_3').value;
var earth= document.getElementById('abc_4').value;
var start = +document.getElementById('abc_5').value;
var stop = +document.getElementById('abc_7').value;

var myArr = [star, moon, sun, earth, start, stop];
for (var i = myArr.length; i++;) for (var j = myArr[i].length; j++)
myArr[i][j].onclick = (function collectData() {
alert( 'hello');
})

}`
```

Comment: You have an array of values and you treat it as an array of arrays, which does not make much sense

Comment: if `existingArr = [];` then you can do `existingArr.push(myArr)` which will the entire array myArr as a single element in existingArr.

Comment: i see that you need to store the function as string value (ex: myArr[i][j] = 'alert("hello")') and when you need to execute use eval(myArr[i][j]) onclick or whatever listener.